# How do I backup hosted elasticsearch locally?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have hosted my elasticsearch on [qbox](https://qbox.io/) free account. It does not allow me to backup my index however I have complete access to data. So I was thinking of backing it up locally. How can I do it?

Is there a tool that can allow me do this easily? Something like `couchDb-futon` where backing up is as simple as providing a url to the remote database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you don't have access to the filesystem where your data is stored, your best bet is iterating through all your documents and indexing them locally through a script.

First, you'd obviously need to recreate the index locally with whatever mappings you've defined on [qbox.io](http://qbox.io).  Then, you could use ElasticSearch's scroll feature (http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/scroll/) to iterate through your documents with a match_all query.  The reason for using scroll is for performance, as normal search requests must aggregate the appropriate resources on each request, whereas scroll allows nodes to persist the resources needed for the ongoing search (per the scroll parameter, which sets the amount of time the nodes will hold on to the relevant resources).

The initial ES operation to fetch the remote documents would look something like this:

```
curl 'http://api_token.api.qbox.io/index_name/_search?scroll=5m' -d '{
  "query": {
    "match_all" : {}
  }
}'
```

There's quite a bit more information on the scroll feature here: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/search-type/.